# Page content only shows after hard refresh and not on redirect

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

How do I redirect to another route without a hard refresh?

I created an ionic / angular app for the first time. It's a survey and after the user answers a set of questions they are redirected to the result page.

My redirect to the result page looks like this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
private router: Router
this.router.navigate(['/result/' + this.current_survey.id]);
```

I only see my results after a hard refresh and I am not sure why.

The code which was the redirect happen is in my survey component and I redirect result component. In the ngOinit() auf result component I retrieve the saved data from web database but at this moment the data not exists.

The code block in survey component looks:

```
if (this.current_survey.finished) {
        this.calculateResult().then((result) => {
          this.current_survey.result = result;
          this.storageService.update(this.current_survey, this.helperService.SURVEY_STORAGE).then(
            (value) => {
            this.storageService.removeKey(this.helperService.LAST_NOT_FINISHED_SURVEY);
            this.router.navigate(['result', this.current_survey.id]);
          });
        });
    }
```

The ngOinit in my result component looks:

```
// Check if survey is a new survey or should be load from previos surveys
    let survey_id;

    // Get id from route, if any id was given in url
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      survey_id = params.get('id');
    });

    if (survey_id !== null) {
      survey_id = parseInt(survey_id, 10);
    }

    this.showResults(survey_id);
```

The method which was called in ngOinit in my result component looks:

```
 const key = this.helperService.SURVEY_STORAGE + '_' + survey_id;
      // Preload all neccessary data
      this.storageService.getDataByName(key).then((data) => {
        if (data.length === 0) {
            this.alertService.show('Error', '', 'Result not found :(');
        } else {
          this.survey = data.shift();
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can provide more information. Where are the results of the survey being stored? If they're stored in a database, in the ngOnInit() method of the results page component you should be able to query the latest result. Another option might be that when you navigate to the results page, you've done so before the result of the survey had finished posting. You may be able to do something like this to ensure it has saved before you try to retrieve the value:

```
save(surveyResults, surveyId) {
    this.someService.postResults(surveyResults)
    .subscribe(() => this.navigate(['result', surveyId]))
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer. I add some additional information and background informations of my code blocks. I think you are right that the db is not ready at the moment if result component try to access. But I put everything in a promise and execute in the "then" block everything step by step to avoid this issue.

Comment: Ah. I think your surveyId hasn't come back in time in order to fetch the results. You might want to look at doing something like
`this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  switchMap(params => this.showResults(params.get('id'))
).subscribe()
`
So you are certain you have your route param before you call showResults.

Comment: thank you for your hint. I try this also but nothing changed. I am not sure how to continue with this issue. For me everything looks good and make sense. In the function showResults I make a console.log and it show the correct surveyId. Maybe the storageService is not ready in my function, but I catch these kind of issue with Promise or I understand Promise and async very bad.